# How to drag and drop multiple objects to specific targets?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am very new to AS3. Of course just ignore the reset button for now. I know my code is big and clunky but I don't mind that for now as it is easily understood by me.

I am trying to match a yellow ball with the yellow goal and green to green and so on.

However every time I try to drag a second object I just can't, the object is stuck, I hear that is the problem with AS3/Flash and the only simple way to solve it is to drag it off the screen which is something I don't want to do.

```
yellowBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDowny)
redBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownr)
blueBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownb)
greenBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDowng)
yellowBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpy) 
redBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpr) 
blueBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpb) 
greenBall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpg) 
resetButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,enterFrameHandlerr);

function mouseDowny(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 yellowBall.startDrag();
} 

function mouseDownr(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 redBall.startDrag();
} 

function mouseDownb(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 blueBall.startDrag();
} 

function mouseDowng(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 greenBall.startDrag();
} 

function mouseUpy(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 yellowBall.stopDrag();
} 

function mouseUpr(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 redBall.stopDrag();
}

function mouseUpb(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 blueBall.stopDrag();
}

function mouseUpg(event:MouseEvent):void { 
 greenBall.stopDrag();
}

function enterFrameHandlerr(event:Event):void{ 
 if(yellowBall.hitTestObject(yellowHome)){ 
 yellowBall.stopDrag();
 yellowBall.x = int(2000); 
 yellowBall.y = int(60);
 }
 if(redBall.hitTestObject(redHome)){ 
 redBall.stopDrag();
 redBall.x = int(425); 
 redBall.y = int(60);
 } 
 if(blueBall.hitTestObject(blueHome)){ 
 blueBall.stopDrag();
 blueBall.x = int(425); 
 blueBall.y = int(275);
 } 
 if(greenBall.hitTestObject(greenHome)){ 
 greenBall.stopDrag();
 greenBall.x = int(55); 
 greenBall.y = int(275);
 }
}


function reset(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 yellowBall.x = int(250); 
 yellowBall.y = int(250);   
};
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Put traces in each function and check if everything works on mouse down/up.

Comment: so you want to drag multiple items at the same time? That's an idea I've never heard of before...

Comment: It isn't clear here what "drag a second object" means - drag at the same time? Since it also appears abandoned I am voting to put on hold as "unclear".